# Selecting multiple row from one row in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following output with me   from multiple tables

```
id    b   c   b     e    b     g  
abc  2   123  3   321   7   876  
abd  2   456  3   452   7   234  
abe  2   0    3   123   7   121  
abf  2   NULL 3   535   7   1212
```

Now I want to insert these values into another table and the insert query for a single command is as follows:

```
insert into resulttable values (id,b,c), (id,b,e) etc.
```

For that I need to do a select  such that it gives me

```
id,b,c
id,b,e etc
```

I dont mind getting rid of b too as it can be selected using c# query.

How can I achieve the same using a single query in sql. Again please note its not a table its an output from different tables

My query should look as follows: from the above I need to do something like

```
select b.a, b.c
union all
select b.d,b.e from  (select a,c,d,e from <set of join>)  b
```

But unfortunately that does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT resulttable
SELECT id, b, c
FROM original
UNION
SELECT id, b, e
FROM original
```

Your example has several columns named 'b' which isn't allowed...

Comment: Should probably be `UNION ALL`, btw

Comment: say this is my select query
(select a,c,d,e from <set of join>) b

Comment: from the above I need to do something like
select b.a, b.c union all select b.d,b.e from  (select a,c,d,e from <set of join>) 
but unfortunately that does not work

Comment: @Amith if that is a join result, you will need to either use table aliases or column aliases - to disambiguate things

Comment: @Amith - `UNION` is your friend anyway. You just need to replace table `original` with what ever query you have or create a temporary table or cte to hold your result set and then use that instead of `original`.

Comment: @marc how can I do the same? I am not sure how to use alias over multple selects

Comment: @mikeal there is really no point for me to send the query all over again. its a loss for me

Comment: `select x.a, x.b, y.a, y.b from sometable x inner join sometable y on [some join condition]`, for example; for a more specific example we'd need to see the query... Otherwise all we can offer is generic pointers

Answer (score 2):

Here, `#tmporigin` refers to your original query that produces the data in the question. Just replace the table name with a subquery.

```
insert into resulttable
select
 o.id,
 case a.n when 1 then b1 when 2 then b2 else b3 end,
 case a.n when 1 then c when 2 then e else g end
from #tmporigin o
cross join (select 1n union all select 2 union all select 3) a
```

---

#### The original answer below, using CTE and union all requiring CTE evaluation 3 times

> I have the following output with me from multiple tables

So set that query up as a Common Table Expression

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   -- the query that produces that output
)
select id,b1,c from CTE
union all
select id,b2,e from CTE
union all
select id,b3,g from CTE
```

**NOTE** - Contrary to popular belief, your CTE while conveniently written once, is run **thrice** in the above query, once for each of the union all parts.

**NOTE ALSO** that if you actually name 3 columns "b" (literally), there is no way to identify which `b` you are referring to in anything that tries to reference the results - in fact SQL Server will not let you use the query in a CTE or subquery.

The following example shows how to perform the above, as well as (if you show the execution plan) revealing that the CTE is run 3 times! (the lines between `--- BELOW HERE` and `--- ABOVE HERE` is a mock of the `original query` that produces the output in the question.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#eav') is not null drop table #eav
;
create table #eav (id char(3), b int, v int)
insert #eav select 'abc', 2, 123
insert #eav select 'abc', 3, 321
insert #eav select 'abc', 7, 876
insert #eav select 'abd', 2, 456
insert #eav select 'abd', 3, 452
insert #eav select 'abd', 7, 234
insert #eav select 'abe', 2, 0
insert #eav select 'abe', 3, 123
insert #eav select 'abe', 7, 121
insert #eav select 'abf', 3, 535
insert #eav select 'abf', 7, 1212

;with cte as (
---- BELOW HERE
    select id.id, b1, b1.v c, b2, b2.v e, b3, b3.v g
    from
    (select distinct id, 2 as b1, 3 as b2, 7 as b3 from #eav) id
    left join #eav b1 on b1.b=id.b1 and b1.id=id.id
    left join #eav b2 on b2.b=id.b2 and b2.id=id.id
    left join #eav b3 on b3.b=id.b3 and b3.id=id.id
---- ABOVE HERE
)
select b1, c from cte
union all
select b2, e from cte
union all
select b3, g from cte
order by b1
```

You would be better off storing the data into a temp table before doing the `union all` select.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this which does not work as you know

```
select b.a, b.c
union all
select b.d,b.e from  (select a,c,d,e from <set of join>)  b
```

You can do this. Union with repeated sub-select

```
select b.a, b.c from (select a,c,d,e from <set of join>)  b
union all
select b.d, b.e from (select a,c,d,e from <set of join>)  b
```

Or this. Repeated use of cte.

```
with cte as
(select a,c,d,e from <set of join>)
select b.a, b.c from cte b
union all
select b.d, b.e from cte b
```

Or use a temporary table variable.

```
declare @T table (a int, c int, d int, e int)
insert into @T values
select a,c,d,e from <set of join>

select b.a, b.c from @T  b
union all
select b.d, b.e from @T  b
```

This code is not tested so there might be any number of typos in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood Your problem correctly, but i have been using something like this for some time:

let's say we have a table

`ID       Val1        Val2

1        A           B

2        C           D`

to obtain a reslut like

`ID       Val

1        A

1        B

2        C

2        D`

You can use a query :

```
select ID, case when i=1 then Val1 when i=2 then Val2 end as Val
from table
left join ( select 1 as i union all select 2 as i ) table_i on i=i
```

which will simply join the table with a subquery containing two values and create a cartesian product. In effect, all rows will be doubled (or multiplied by how many values the subquery will have). You can vary the number of values depending on how many varsions of row You'll need. Depending on the value of i, Val will be Val1 or Val2 from original table. If you'll see the execution plan, there will be a warning that the join has no join predicates (because of i=i), but it is ok - we want it. 
This makes queries a bit large (in terms of text) because of all the case when, but are quite easy to read if formatted right. I needed it for stupid tables like "BigID, smallID1, smallID2...smallID11" that was spread across many columns I don't know why.
Hope it helps.
Oh, I use a static table with 10000 numbers, so i just use

```
join tab10k on i<=10
```

for 10x row.
I apologize for stupid formatting, I'm new here.